# Merged Cells from Excel are not reflecting in Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have an excel with the following format
[My excel file has 3 columns Emp.Id, Employee Name, Designation each of which have two cells merged and then you have other columns which are not merged.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdzUw.png)

Now when I am importing the excel file and showing its contents in grid view, the merged cells are showing as two separate cells and the cell value is being displayed in the first cell and second one is empty
[It is showing merged cell as two separate cells and instead merging the column sunday as both are empty cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQuXZ.png)

I tried this code

```
protected DataTable YourExcelFileProcessingMethod(Stream excelFileStream)
{
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(excelFileStream))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Column" + col);
        }

        for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();

            for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
            {
                ExcelRange cell = worksheet.Cells[row, col];

                if (cell.Merge)
                {
                    
                    newRow[col - 1] = cell.Merge && cell.Start.Row == row ? cell.Text : cell.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    newRow[col - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        return dt;
    }
}

protected void btnImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadAttendance.HasFile)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = FileUploadAttendance.PostedFile;

        if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xls") || file.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx") || file.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsm"))
        {
            DataTable dt = YourExcelFileProcessingMethod(file.InputStream);

            GridAttendance.DataSource = dt;
            GridAttendance.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "FailureAlert", "alert('Only Excel files are accepted');", true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "FailureAlert", "alert('Please Select a file to import');", true);
    }
}


protected void GridAttendance_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int rowIndex = GridAttendance.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = GridAttendance.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = GridAttendance.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < gvRow.Cells.Count;
                                                      cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text ==
                                   gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan =
                        gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- This if block is unnecessary and equals to `newRow[col - 1] = cell. Text;` :

```
if (cell. Merge)
                {
                    newRow[col - 1] = cell.Merge && cell.Start.Row == row ? cell. Text : cell. Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    newRow[col - 1] = cell. Text;
                }
```

2- To merge cells, the `RowDataBound` is not the proper event because all gridview data is needed. It can be done after `GridAttendance.DataBind();`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Bind();
    }
}

private void Bind()
{
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/77388146.xlsx");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filepath))
    {
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
            for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(worksheet.Columns[col].Range.Start.Address.Replace("1",""));
            }
            for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
                {
                    newRow[col - 1] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].ToText();
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();

            for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.Columns; col++)
            {
                for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
                {
                    ExcelRange cell = worksheet.Cells[row, col];
                    if (cell.Merge && cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        gv.Rows[row - 1].Cells[col - 1].RowSpan++;
                        int start_row = row;
                        row++;
                        while (
                            worksheet.Cells[row, col].Merge &&
                            worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value == null &&
                            row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row)
                        {
                            gv.Rows[start_row - 1].Cells[col - 1].RowSpan++;
                            gv.Rows[row - 1].Cells[col - 1].Visible = false;
                            row++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: results]

This is a raw code and may need fine-tuning.