# Multiple values under single Table cell

Tags: c#, html, datatable, blazor

I am currently creating a website, but I am uncertain how to tackle this problem. I am trying to create a display for a DataTable using HTML and C#, that should be sortable, but I would like to do something specific.

I have a list of objects that contains a `Name` and a `Value`, both are strings. I was wondering whether it is possible to insert multiple values (`Name`) under a single cell, but also making it possible to show the `Value` while hovering over the name.

[image: Example DataTable]

Here is an example I made in Excel, where a row contains multiple values. The underlined String should be hoverable and show the `Value` as tooltip.

Comment: It is not clear in which part you have problem: creating the data table, or displaying the data. For storing data, you can either use two tables (master and detail) or a single table (child specs with parented). To display data like merged cells in excel, you can use row-span/column-scan in html table or gridview.

Comment: Take a look at : [Merged Cells from Excel are not reflecting in Grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388146/merged-cells-from-excel-are-not-reflecting-in-grid-view)

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh I'm sorry, I meant a display to showcase the data on the webpage. Thank you for your answer. I think a HTML table is what I need.

Comment: Yes it is possible but you should give us what you tried and the specific issues you are having, separately. There is also a high change those are already answered on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HTML: Both rowspan and tooltip added.   
 <body>
         <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td>Jill</td>
            <td>Jill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Phone</th>
            <td class="tooltip">555-1234 <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></td>
            <td>555-1234</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tooltip">555-1234 <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
             <td class="tooltip">555-1234 <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <td>555-1234</td>
            <td>555-1234</td>
          </tr>
          </table>
           
           <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
          <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
            </div>
           
          <script src="script.js"></script>
        </body>
       
CSS:

table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, no problem.